# Hava pdf files attachments into salesforce rendered as page 2 of a visualforce page renderAs=PDF

Tags: salesforce

On an custom object I have attachment files associated with it. The files are pdf. I would like to generate visualforce page where the first page is the mailing address associated with the custom object, and the page 2 is the attachment file (which is a pdf). The visualforce page has the RenderAs='pdf' attribute. How can I do this? I am familiar with extensions and how to query the body of an attachment.

Comment: I think that is not possible to convert the pdf attachment body into an html format in order to perform the renderAs=PDF. At least, It seems to be complicated. Why not open the attach in the page 2 ? something like https://XXXX.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=attachId

Comment: Hello Martin. I am not sure I understand. Are you saying there is a way to set the content on page 1 independently than the one on page 2. Therefore I could set the mailing address to be a renderAs='pdf' of a visualforce page, and page 2 to be the attachment. How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

I would just move all attachment to other server (like amazon) and provide link of it in page 1